# How to print a value from output

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd, output

I would like to know how to print a value instead of the whole output, for ex.: `ping google.com -t`

> output - Reply from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: byt=32 time=35 TTL=52

and i would like to have: "time=35" only or the number only - "35"
If you  know how to help me please help me :D 
Thanks P.

Answer (score 2):

from command line

```
for /f "eol=P skip=2 tokens=5 delims= " %# in ('ping google.com -t -n 10') do @if "%#" neq "=" @if  "%#" neq "in" @echo %#
```

from batch file:

```
for /f "eol=P skip=2 tokens=5 delims= " %%# in ('ping google.com -t -n 10') do @if "%%#" neq "=" @if  "%%#" neq "in" @echo %%#
```

If you not set `-n 10` you'll have to wait until `for /f` buffer is full.